# wxScrollBar set position and range

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

The documentation of wxScrollBar is quite confusing to me. I would like to know what method to use in order to set the position of thumbnail in a wx.ScrollBar
In a wx.Slider it is quite simple

```
slider = wx.Slider(...)
slider.SetMin(min) # set the minimum value
slider.SetMax(max) # set the maximum value
slider.SetValue(val) # set the slider position
```

with a ScrollBar I am very confused and not able to reproduce anything similar to the later. The doc is not quite clear to me and it appears that the only method that one can use is to reset the scrollbar using SetScrollbar method which is also not very understandable to me how to use it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed use [wxScrollBar::SetScrollbar()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_scroll_bar.html#ae69c239fd6af4ebcabf46efa9fc5092e) to change the scrollbar position. It's true that it's more complicated than `wxSlider::SetValue()`, but this is because a scrollbar has more "degrees of liberty", i.e. you can choose its page size and thumb size too. But the remark in the documentation link above seems to provide a nice example explaining how to use it, so I'm not sure what exactly is unclear about it?

Also notice that you very rarely use `wxScrollBar` control directly, typically you work with the window scrollbars and for them you can use a simpler [wxWindow::SetScrollPos()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_window.html#afbf4dc9064cf70cfe6884554b97a27bf) function.